# Is it possible to use thread_info() or pthread_mach_thread_np() to know if a thread has been terminated on OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, pthreads

I am trying to implement something similar to `pthread_tryjoin_np` on OSX.
For this purpose I need a reliable way to find if a pthreat_t has been terminated.

I found the mach_port API and I am wondering if I can use thread_info() for this usecase.
https://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/gnumach-doc/Thread-Information.html

```
#include <mach/mach_init.h>
#include <mach/thread_act.h>
#include <mach/mach_port.h>

bool info_available(mach_port_t thread)
{
    mach_msg_type_number_t count = THREAD_BASIC_INFO_COUNT;
    thread_basic_info_data_t info;
    kern_return_t kr = thread_info(thread, THREAD_BASIC_INFO, (thread_info_t) &info, &count);
    if (kr == KERN_SUCCESS && (info.flags & TH_FLAGS_IDLE) == 0) {
        std::cout << "thread runnable state: " << info.run_state << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout << "invalid call to display info, thread might not be available: " << kr << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
}

void* thread_info_func(void *parameters)
{
    info_available(mach_thread_self());
    sleep(8);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_attr_t thread_attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&thread_attr);
    
    int create_result = pthread_create(&thread, &thread_attr, thread_info_func, NULL);
    mach_port_t test_port = pthread_mach_thread_np(thread);

    // works display running 1 or waiting 3
    info_available(test_port);

    pthread_join(m_thread, NULL);
    
    // return 0, is is standard ? Is it reliable ?
    mach_port_t test_port = pthread_mach_thread_np(thread);
    // bool thread_terminated = test_port == MACH_PORT_NULL;

    // doesn't work, kr == KERN_INVALID_ARGUMENT
    info_available(test_port);

    // reliable ?
    // thread_terminated = !info_available();
}
```

`thread_info()` should return TH_STATE_HALTED if the thread has been terminated but I suppose it fails if the thread doesn't exist anymore. In my case thread_info exits with KERN_INVALID_ARGUMENT. Should it mean the thread doesn't exist anymore?

On a side note can `pthread_mach_thread_np(thread)` returning 0 also mean the thread has been terminated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

macOS has a function called [`pthread_getschedparam`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/pthread_setschedparam.3.html) which takes a `pthread_t` as a parameter and returns an error (`ESRCH`) if the thread ID passed in doesn't represent a running thread.

You still run the risk that the thread you're interested in has ended and a new one has been launched which winds up with the same thread ID.  I don't know how quickly they are recycled so you'd have to run some tests to see how much of a problem this actually is in practise.

Comment: pthread_getschedparam seems to also to do the job, pthread_mach_thread_np looks simpler in this regard: https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-498/pthreads/pthread.c

Comment: @Paltoquet Simpler how?  You're asking if the code you posted will do what you want.  The answer is: I don't know.  But I know for a fact that the code in my answer works because I use it myself, so if you're looking for an *opinion*, then that is mine.

Comment: Sorry, I have removed my answer before, this comment was not relevant. ```pthread_mach_thread_np``` and ```pthread_getschedparam``` both contain the same body when checking if the thread is still valid. ```pthread_mach_thread_np``` is shorter and doesn't need extra arguments. Both method should do fine, sadly it didn't work in my codebase, I assume the thread I tested didn't get terminated correctly. Thanks by the way.

Comment: @Paltoquet _sadly it didn't work in my codebase_ That's odd, what didn't work?  (And how did it fail?)

Comment: Need to ran more tests but the thread I was looking never seem to stop, if I called pthread_join instead I got the appropriate result. I would keep you updated If I find more. Even weirder run_state stored in thread_basic_info_data_t  return INTMAX instead of a value between 0 and 5

Answer (score 0):

This is the actual source code of pthread.c:
https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-498/pthreads/pthread.c

```
mach_port_t
pthread_mach_thread_np(pthread_t t)
{
    mach_port_t kport = MACH_PORT_NULL;

    if (_pthread_lookup_thread(t, &kport, 0) != 0)
        return(NULL);

    return(kport);
}
```

`pthread_mach_thread_np` seems to be a good match if you want to know if a thread still exists. Note on my system the pthread_t is a pointer to a complex struct.

```
int
_pthread_find_thread(pthread_t thread)
{
    pthread_t p;

loop:
    TAILQ_FOREACH(p, &__pthread_head, plist) {
        if (p == thread) {
            if (thread->kernel_thread == MACH_PORT_NULL) {
                UNLOCK(_pthread_list_lock);
                sched_yield();
                LOCK(_pthread_list_lock);
                goto loop;
            } 
            return(0);
        }
    }
    return(ESRCH);
}
```

The function seems to be doing some pointer comparison, If you are confident no new threads will spawn in the same memory location. The function is safe.